# How can I do computed state transitions without offending the borrow checker?

Tags: rust, state, borrow-checker

I've written this code for transitioning between states, but if fails to pass the borrow checker:

```
struct State {
    // ...
}

impl State {
    fn next(self) -> (Self, u32) {
        // ...
    }
}

struct StateHolder {
    state: State
}

impl StateHolder {
    fn next_value(&mut self) -> u32 {
         // ERROR: Cannot move out of borrowed context
         let (new_state, byproduct) = self.state.next(); 
         self.state = new_state;
         return byproduct;
    }
}
```

This seems like the kind of situation where I'd usually use `std::mem::replace`, but since the value of `new_state` depends on the old state, it just won't work here.

I know I could make this work by making `State` implement `Clone` and doing this:

```
fn next_value(&mut self) -> u32 {
    let (new_state, byproduct) = self.state.clone().next(); 
    self.state = new_state;
    return byproduct;
}
```

But I'd rather not do an unnecessary copy like that, or require `State` to implement `Clone`. (I think the compiler would optimize the copy out in this case, but I don't want to rely on that.)

I also know of quite a few ways to do this in unsafe Rust, but that seems way overkill for such a simple and obviously safe pattern.

Is there a way to do write this in safe Rust, without unnecessary copying?

Comment: *such a [...] obviously safe pattern* — It's **not** obviously safe though. If a panic were to occur between the time that you removed the value and the time you replaced it, then you'd be invoking undefined behavior when the destructor of the structure is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> u32;
```

I'll be honest and say that it feels really weird to both consume and return `self`, and it's also impractical as demonstrated here.

---

If you are stuck with `fn next(self) -> (Self, u32)` but are willing to alter the layout of `StateHolder`, go with `state: Option<State>`, because `Option` has `take`:

```
let (new_state, byproduct) = self.state.take().unwrap().next();
self.state = Some(new_state);
byproduct
```

If you are stuck without `Option`, or it's too painful to use, then you can indeed use `std::mem::replace`, but you'll need some `State` to do so. This is easy if `State` implements `Default`, but may be expensive:

```
let (new_state, byproduct) =
    std::mem::replace(&mut self.state, State::default()).next();
std::mem::replace(&mut self.state, new_state);
byproduct
```

Finally, you can indeed break `unsafe` to move the value out of `self.state`... however if the computation ever panics before you get to fill it back then you have opened the door to Undefined Behavior land, and that's baaad.

Comment: After experimenting with my code more, I've realized it is idiomatic and silly to do what I wanted to do. (Even if it would produce more general and elegant code.) I appreciate how your answer addressed a bunch of better ways to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @Others: No worries, Rust is young enough that we're all exploring the possibilities here :)